# Unable to create a Pause,Restart,and Home button dialog for swift Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I made a simple game with swift spritekit and I was planning to implement a button that will display a dialog box and was searching around on tutorials on custom dialog but found none that helped me. I know how to make a simple dialog with with a UIView, but the problem is I have no clue how to make a custom dialog box that gives you options to transition to main menu, restart the game and such. I've found [How can I pause a game in SpriteKit and SceneKit - SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823116/how-can-i-pausing-a-game-in-spritekit-and-scenekit-swift) but still not enough.
I managed to make a dialog box with a UIView but I cannot transition to other gamescene, and I also cannot customize the looks of it that suits my games atomsphere. If there is some tips or samples that are easyto percieve will be great since I started swift just recently. I would love to hear from you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was quite simple, I was able to implement a custom dialog that would transition to the  main menu after using the SKScene parameter that has been passed into the init() within the class that extends the UIView.